# How to Compare Current "Time and Minutes" in LINQ using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

How to Compare Current "Time and Minutes" in LINQ Queries using C# Language

Please any one know tell me How?

Example:This is my Time = 08:30 
        Compare to current time(9:30) 
        using LINQ Queries
        if Yes return true
        otherwise False;
By mohan
Please.

Comment: And what is "Yes" when comparing two times? `==` ? "no more than [x] time apart"? or...?

Comment: Is you "Time"(i would say hours) and Minutes is string or DateTime?

Comment: Why LINQ? LINQ works on sequences, there is no sequence here.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Run some code at a specific time of the day? I think the first part of your solution is already misguided, because this kind of equality comparison with time is unlikely to be the answer to your real problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare just hours and minutes, then do that:

```
public bool CompareTimes(DateTime time1, DateTime time2)
{
   return time1.Hours == time2.Hours && time1.Minutes == time2.Minutes;
}
```

Comment: Note that if you factor it out to a method, you can't use it in `IQueryable` based LINQ anymore. I'd also throw in a `Contract.Requires(time1.Kind==time2.Kind)` for good measure.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime now=DateTime.UtcNow;//Or .Now if you *really* want to
return (now.Minutes==myTime.Minutes)&&(now.Hours==myTime.Hours);
```

It's not LINQ, but LINQ doesn't make any sense here, since LINQ works on sequence, and there is no sequence here.

Note that I'm evaluating `DateTime.Now`/`UtcNow` only once, to avoid race conditions. Another reason for doing this is that it isolates the clock(which represents external mutable state) from the logic for easier testability. Consider making it a parameter to your function.

Depending on the timezone of `myTime`, you'll need `DateTime.UtcNow`, `DateTime.Now` or even more complex maths involving `DateTimeOffset` and `TimeZoneInfo`.

---

But your whole idea of comparing the current time to a reference time with equality checks might be flawed. If your program doesn't get any CPU time during that one minute interval it won't notice that the specified time has passed. One example where this happens is hibernation or sleep. Another is when the clock suddenly jumps, due to daylight-saving, or just because it drifted too far, and windows contacted a NTP server.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a LINQ query to compare time.

You can simply do

`bool equal = dateTime1.Equals(dateTime2)`

if both are same equal will have `true` value otherwise `false`

Answer (score 0):

Just any of

```
x.Date == DateTime.Now
```

or

```
x.Date > DateTime.Now
```

or

```
(DateTime.Now - x.Date).TotalMinutes > someNumber
```

etc

Watch out you might need `UtcNow` if `x.Date` is in UTC time.

Comment: Was there a grace period edit? Your answer doesn't really match the question atm.

Comment: @CodeInChaos I disagree; the OP is talking about comparing 2 dates, but doesn't indicate *how* they need to compare them, so I've presented various options. They talk about comparing some value ("my time") to the current time, which is what I show. You've interpreted a **really vague** question one way; I've interpreted it another way (and asked for clarification, which was ignored)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (DateTime.Now == myTime)
     return true;
else return false;
```

based on the comments below:

```
return DateTime.Now == myTime;
```

Comment: aka `return DateTime.Now == myTime;`

Comment: Why do you need if statement? just `return DateTime.now == myTime;`